# Restoring the entire list to a certain date in SharePoint online

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-online, restore

It is possible to restore an **entire** list in SharePoint online (**not individual items**) to a certain date; for example,  restoring the list to how it was last week. Is there any possibility to make versions of the lists.

Comment: do you have versioning enabled?

Comment: @Gwny versioning would only help for list items not the list itself.

Comment: @Gwny as said Akhoy, we can enable versioning only for individual items not for the list.